# Copying part of char array into new char array fails

Tags: c, pointers, arrays

I want to copy a part of char array into a new one

```
void match(char* probe, char* pattern)
char* matchText;
//the char-array probe in this example is at least 12 characters long
//I'm only writing numbers in the strncopy-command to make it easier to understand
strncpy (matchText, probe + 5, 5 );
```

Upon running that the debugger quits with an error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error is it? Are the arrays properly allocated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate memory to `matchText`, what you have is just an pointer.
It must have enough memory allocated using `malloc`(since it is a pointer) to hold the string being copied in to it, or what you get is **Undefined Behavior**.